# Need to display three Apache Trinidad charts in three columns instead of the default two

Tags: apache, jsf, charts, trinidad

I have created three charts using the Apache Trinidad chart component and I am having trouble customizing the display of the charts. By default, the charts (or gauges in my case) are displayed in two columns so that the third charts is displayed on a second row beneath the first. (See image below for an example).

I would the gauges to be displayed in three columns so that they are all on the same row side by side. I have looked at all the attributes for the component but still can not figure out how to do it.

(See the attributes here. http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_chart.html)

The code I am using in my jsp is shown below.

```
<tr:chart id="orderStatusGauge" type="circularGauge" 
value="#{orderStatusBacking.gaugeModel}" YMinorGridLineCount="4"
inlineStyle="width:450px; height:325px;"/>
```

I have already tried to adjust the inline style width and height and that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Any ideas? All help will be greatly appreciated.

[Example http://www.vogella.de/articles/ApacheMyFaces/images/graphics10.gif](http://www.vogella.de/articles/ApacheMyFaces/images/graphics10.gif)